Data Binding seems to be broken
I am working on a layout designer, think of WinForms Designer for Web-Components, and am at the very beginning of the project. I use Blazor Server App, and, as I need to generically generate controls, am using DynamicComponents. As I don't want too much complexity within the actual layout components, I've got a base class which takes care of most common things. Additionally, I have created a Selectable node to allow detection of component selection without the need to implement that in every component.
When a component is now selected, I see that the delete icon is not getting enabled but its disabled/enabled state is correctly set by the code.
I could, however, call StateHasChanged and that would show the correct state but unfortunately lead to other issues, most likely related to the DynamicComponents being used.
I was able to reproduce my problem with a very simple example which can be found here:
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QYcIuybXTEvcExgs
My full code can be found here:
https://github.com/Romout/LayoutDesigner
The problem is that when adding an alpha numeric and selecting it by clicking on it, the delete icon on top is not activated which indicates, that the data binding for 'DeleteDisabled' did not work.
I will try to outline the simple example code here as well:
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<PageTitle>BlazorRepro</PageTitle>
@Counter

<Container @ref="@container">
<div>
    @Body
</div>
</Container>

@code {
    Container? container;
    int Counter { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);

        if (container != null && firstRender)
            container.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
    }

    private void OnSelectionChanged()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine($"Counter incremented to : {++Counter}");
    }
}

That's the main component. It generates a Container instance which, in turn, will provide a CascadingValue to all children. It also registers for the SelectionChanged event and increments a counter when ever something is selected (= Enabling/Disabling of my delete button)
<div class="container">
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter] 
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    public event Action? SelectionChanged;

    public void Select()
    {
        SelectionChanged?.Invoke();
    }
}

Container implementation. As mentioned, it provides a CascadingValue and also a public method to be able to be notified about a new selection.
<div @onclick="Select">
    @ChildContent
</div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public Container Container { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    private void Select()
    {
        Container.Select();
    }
}

The Selectable implementation. When ever something is clicked, the Container.Select() method is invoked.
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<Selectable>
    <h1>Click me to select</h1>
</Selectable>

Finally, the body of the MainLayout - It just wraps a selectable text.
If 'Click me to select' is clicked, I would expect the counter on the main layout to be incremented but unfortunately, that only happens if the event handler of the main layout is also calling StateHasChanged.
I am not exactly sure where the problem comes from but I know, that that kind of binding should work in general.
Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions!

This is one possible change you could make - there are other ways.
Create a CounterDisplay component:
@counter
@code {
    int counter = 0;

    public void Increment() 
    {
        counter++;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

Add this component to your layout:
<CounterDisplay @ref=counter />

Declare a local for the @ref
CounterDisplay counter;
And change your handler:
private void OnSelectionChanged()
{
    counter?.Increment();
}

Now the CounterDisplay is in charge of its own counter and can call StateHasChanged to update itself in isolation when you call Increment
Try it here

As mentioned, the StateHasChanged() call works, but leads to other issues (it rebinds the dynamic components with old data which, in turn, deletes all user changes to properties of the components)
Edit: I see that you moved everything to a Counter method but my actual case is different, the counter was only an example. The interesting part of all of this is, that, if you add a normal button which calls the same method OnSelectionChanged(), the data binding acts as expected so the difference must be somewhere in the call tree in case that the method is invoked via a normal .net event.

If you ask for help make sure it is a relevant question

Okay, I see what you mean. I maybe made the example to simple. I will provide my whole code to make my problem more clear.

I made my repo public and added the link to the repository. Maybe that makes my issue more clear.
